# Struggling with foreach

Tags: powershell, printing

I'm rather new and, well, awful at this whole scripting thing: so any help would be appreciated.

Basically I am trying to create a PowerShell script that installs an undefined number of printers on an undefined number of computers. The computer names and printer names will come from local text files.

This is what I have so far:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential
$printerlist = Get-Content c:\setup\printers.txt
get-content c:\setup\names.txt | foreach-object {foreach($printer in $printerlist){rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /ge /c $_ /n  $printer}}
```

EDIT: I am getting the error, unable to enumerate per machine printer connections operation could not be completed (error 0x0000007b) I have tried modifying the script anyway i can come up with, which is probably fewer ways than it should be.

Comment: Are you getting an error? This seems more of a statement than a request for help with something.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What is not working, and what have you tried?

Comment: /ge lists the connections to printers on a given computer. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057.aspx

Comment: I am getting the error, unable to enumerate per machine printer connections operation could not be completed (error 0x0000007b)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have an issue with your foreach loop here.

I think it's just the usage of `rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry`

Install printer:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /c "\\COMPUTER_NAME" /n "\\PRINT_SERVER_NAME\PRINTER_NAME"
```

Sets default printer:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /c "\\COMPUTER_NAME" /n "\\PRINT_SERVER_NAME\PRINTER_NAME"
```

Try installing with the `/in` individually for one computer from powershell console without your script to see if you still get the same error, could be a permission but I don't think so.